# I want to decode Speex raw data

Tags: c++, decoder, speex

I want to convert Speex raw data to playable wav files in my c++ program.

So, for first step, I should be able to decode Speex raw data to PCM.

and in next step, i should make suitable header for PCM files (for playing).

Are these steps correct?

If yes, any help about first step (decode Speex raw data to PCM) would be appreciated,

and if not, I would be grateful for any recommendation about this process!

Comment: To decode Speex data, use a library or the Speex specification.

Comment: Thanks Oswald, but is there any c code sample about it?

Comment: http://www.speex.org/

Comment: there is not any code sample for decoding speex **raw** data at speex.org.

Comment: I've found [sampledec](http://www.speex.org/docs/manual/speex-manual/node13.html) for decoding speex stream (raw data) but the main problem is **adding suitable header**. any help?